# Persist screenshot sketch tool setting

Tags: macos, preview, screen-capture

Every time I take a screenshot and I need to mark some areas I reach out to the **Sketch** tool and just draw. By default, if I draw an arrow or a circle shape it automatically changes them to a crisp arrow or a perfect circle.

I don't want that and I keep clicking on this button, marked with an arrow, to preserve my own drawing. Is there a way to persist this setting so I don't have to do it over and over again?

[image: Screenshot of the Preview app with the 'Sketch' tool selected]